# How to prohibit GCC from dropping unused function when linked static library?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I have an application linked with a few static libraries. And this application will load a dynamic library through dlopen. And the dynamic library will call a function which came from one of the static library.

I can only find the function in the static library throught "nm", whose label is "T". But I can't find it in the application.

I have tried `-Wl,--whole-archive`, but it seems that many "multiple definition" occur. Maybe because I can't add this flag only before the one static library.

So how to fix this issue?

Comment: you can use whole archive then turn it off with `--no-whole-archive` after you have referenced your library. Can you show us your build/script file?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It is hard to add such ld flag before individual library, due to damn make framework. I have tried to compile them into dynamic library. Everything is ok now. But I still be curious about the solution for static library.

Comment: there's another way if you need just a function: reference it from your application from a function that you're not calling. But maybe the issue is just that you cannot call this static lib from your dynamic lib. your dynamic lib must be linked against the static lib. Create a [mcve] (i know it can be time consuming) and we'll be able to provide a solution

Comment: Don't blame the tool if you're the one who writes its input. `make` knows nothing about C or how to link. Its your Makefile that gives you headaches. ;-)